# JFrame and FrameView object interaction?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans6.8

How is it possible to access a FrameView (Being the main panel view) object from a JFrame and vice versa??!

Comment: It is generally the case that an application needs only a single `JFrame`.  Other floating GUI elements should probably be dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Given a [FrameView](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/jmat/io/gui/FrameView.html) is a `JFrame`, exactly the same way you might do it for a `JFrame`.

If you don't know how to do it with another `JFrame`, maybe you should post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) (using core J2SE classes only) of your best attempt.

Comment: I got how its done Andrew.  I passed the instance of the originating FrameView class to the opening JFrame through a call to it's constructor!  Now I have access to the Object elements!  I now have a little issue with Netbeans.  The project I have set up can't find all the classes in the main application package.  Where do you think I can set this up in Netbeans so that my Application classes are seen again??!